# Gmail search | How to search for subjects match a string 100% only?

Tags: search, gmail

This is my target subject string: "PSVN Invoice 2103_535"

I did the search

```
subject:("PSVN Invoice 2103_535")
```

The result shows

```
OP_PSVNCN// PSVN Invoice 2103_535 => It's not 100% matched, how to exclude this result?

PSVN Invoice 2103_535             => It's 100% matched, how to only include this result only?
```

[See screenshot for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtI5a.png)

Answer (score 0):

just search: "PSVN" "Invoice" "2103_535"

Comment: Sorry but it still shows the same result. Here are what I tried *** [subject("PSVN" "Invoice" "2103_535" ) ]   *** ["PSVN" "Invoice" "2103_535" ]